# ng-content for input type text placeholder

Tags: angular

I am creating reusable custom input components in the project and used ng-content for dynamic content projection for input headings, however, I want to know is there a way to have a content projection for input placeholder? note that the place holder is of type **Number**

I used saw someone done it for the type text input and I tried for myself did not work

```
<div class="input-container">
  <span class="input-heading-text">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </span>
  <input type="number"  [placeholder]="text.innerHTML"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you pass it as an input to your custom input component?

Comment: could you demonstrate with some examples?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l3wsyd

Comment: I think its smarter to go with a input like suggested in the answers. If you still want to go with Content Projection have a look at `contentChild/ren`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to declare a property and use input decorator so you can pass data from the parent component

```
  @Input() placeholder:string = "";
  @Input() label:string;
```

*template*

```
<div class="input-container">
  <span class="input-heading-text" *ngIf="label">
  {{label}}
  </span>
  <input type="number"  [placeholder]="placeholder"/>
</div>
```

> you can still use ng-content for label part where you want to pass an html markup not just a text but the best case for the placeholder is to pass the value to a property same as the example below

*parent component*

```
<input-elm label="user name" placeholder="your name...."></input-elm>
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-whmgkc)

Answer (score 1):

declare a variable named placeholder(or anything you like) in your component ts file, then

```
<input type="number"  [placeholder]="placeholder" />
```